# How can I send a array dictionary to php server SWIFT 4

Tags: php, swift

How can I send an array dictionary to php server?

For example:

```
var dict:[string:Int] = ["1":32,"2":33,"3":"34"]
```

I want to send "dict" value to php server.
I use this code but not work.

```
 func reorderDevice(_ link:String)
{

    let url = NSURL(string: serverSettings + "reorderDeviceType.php") 

    var request = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    var dataString = secretCode


    dataString = dataString + (link)
    let dataD = dataString.data(using: .utf8) // convert to utf8 string

    do
    {


        let uploadJob = URLSession.shared.uploadTask(with: request, from: dataD)
        {
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil {

            }
        }
        uploadJob.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to be more specific than this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use alamofire [Alamofire swift](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)

```
func sendData(param: [String:Any], headers: [String:String], completion: @escaping (Int,NSDictionary) -> Void)
{
    checkInternet()
    alamoFireManager!.request("URL OF API OR SERVER" method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
        if let status = response.response?.statusCode
        {
            if let info = response.result.value as? NSDictionary
            {
                completion(status,info)
            }
            else
            {
                completion(status,["message":"error with the answer"])
            }
        }
        else
        {
            completion(500,["message":"not found"])
        }
    }
}

let param = [
        "data": yourDictionary
        ] as [String : Any]
let headers = [
        "Authorization": "token if you have"
    ]
sendData (param: param, headers: headers) { (status, info) in
{
    print(status)
    print(info)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to send an array as the `httpBody`, use the following code

```
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "YOUR-URL")!)
    let  dict : [String: Int] = ["1":32,"2":33,"3": 34]

    let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = data
```

If you have different types of form data  try the below approach

```
 let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "YOUR-URL")!)
 let  dict : [String: Int] = ["1":32,"2":33,"3": 34]
 let formData = createBodyWithParameters(parameters: dict)
 let task = URLSession.shared.uploadTask(with: request, from: formData){
      data, response, error in
      if error != nil {
      }
 }
 task.resume()
```

The `createBodyWithParameters` method

```
func createBodyWithParameters(parameters: [String: Any]) -> Data? {
    guard parameters.count != 0  else {
        return nil
    }
    var formData = Data()
    let boundary = UUID().uuidString
    for (key, value) in parameters {
       // Appending formData
       formData.append("\r\n--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
       formData.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
       formData.append("\(value)".data(using: .utf8)!)
    }

    // Add other fields or params here if any

    // Make sure to close form data with boundary 
    formData.append("\r\n--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
    return formData
}
```

To append secret code to form data

```
// To append secret code
let secretCode = "code"
let key = "Key"
formData.append("\r\n--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
formData.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
formData.append("\(secretCode)".data(using: .utf8)!)
formData.append("\r\n--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
```

Complete code to append secretKey and params

```
func createBodyWithParameters(parameters: [String: Any] , secretCodeKey : String , secretCodeValue : String) -> Data? {

   var formData = Data()
   let boundary = UUID().uuidString
   for (key, value) in parameters {
      // Appending formData
      formData.append("\r\n--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
      formData.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
      formData.append("\(value)".data(using: .utf8)!)
   }

   // Add other fields or params here if any


   // To append secret code

   formData.append("\r\n--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
   formData.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(secretCodeKey)\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
   formData.append("\(secretCodeValue)".data(using: .utf8)!)


   formData.append("\r\n--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)



   return formData
}
```